# How can all (`all`) be true while none (`any`) are true at the same time?

Tags: r, logic, comparison

```r
a <- character()
b <- "SO is great"

any(a == b) 
#> [1] FALSE

all(a == b)
#> [1] TRUE
```

The manual describes ‘any’ like this
*Given a set of logical vectors, is at least one of the values true?*
So, not even one value in the comparison `a == b` yields TRUE.
If that is the case how can ‘any’ return FALSE while ‘all’ returns TRUE? ‘all’
is described as *Given a set of logical vectors, are all of the values true?*.

In a nutshell: all values are TRUE and none are TRUE at the same time?
I am not expert but that looks odd.

Questions:

1. Is there a reasonable explanation for or is it just some quirk of R?
2. What are the ways around this?

<sup>Created on 2021-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That's because `a == b` is empty here (cause `a` is empty).

Comment: Take a look at https://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/044fjep5rq/r-all-logical-0-and-any-logical-0/oldest

Comment: The full sentence you quoted from the manual is: "The value returned is ‘TRUE’ if at least one of the values in ‘x’  is ‘TRUE’, and ‘FALSE’ if all of the values in ‘x’ are ‘FALSE ’**(including if there are no values)**" (emphasis added)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, when comparing `a == b` the elements of the shorter vector are recycled as necessary. However, in your case `a` has no elements, so no recycling occurs and the result is an empty logical vector.

The results of `any(a == b)` and `all(a == b)` are coherent with the logical quantifiers *for all* and *exists*. If you quantify on an empty range, *for all* gives the neutral element for logical conjunction (AND) which is `TRUE`, while *exists* gives the neutral element for logical disjunction (OR) which is `FALSE`.

As to how avoid these situations, check if the vectors have the same size, since comparing vectors of different lengths rarely makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding question number 2, I know of `identical`. It works well in all the situations I can think of.

```r
a <- "a"
b <- "b"
identical(a, b) # FALSE >> works
#> [1] FALSE

a <- character(0)
identical(a, b) # FALSE >> works
#> [1] FALSE

a <- NA
identical(a, b) # FALSE >> works
#> [1] FALSE

a <- NULL
identical(a, b) # FALSE >> works
#> [1] FALSE

a <- b
identical(a, b) # TRUE >> works
#> [1] TRUE
```

`identical` seems to be a good workaround though it still feels like a workaround to a part-time developer like me. Are there more solutions? Better ones? And why does R behave like this in the first place (see question)?

<sup>Created on 2021-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: There is a Note in `?all` : "That `all(logical(0))` is true is a useful convention: it ensures that `all(all(x), all(y)) == all(x, y)` even if `x` has length zero." `a == b` is of length zero.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 1)
I have no idea whether I am correct, but here are my thoughts:

In R `all()` is the compliment of `any()`.  For consistency, `all(logical(0))` is true.  So, you're situation you are capturing this unique case.

In mathematics, this is analogous to a set being both open and closed.  I'm not a computer scientist, so I can't really talk to why one of the greybeards from way back when implemented this in either R or S.

regarding question 2)
I think the other responses have answered this well.

Comment: In mathematics any property about the elements of the empty set is true, because there's no element in the empty set so you cannot find one for which the property is not true. This has nothing to do with open and closed.

Comment: yeah, you are correct. I was thinking it was analogous b/c they both depend on understanding a specific aspect of their definition.

Answer (score 0):

Another **solution** provided by the [shiny package](https://shiny.rstudio.com/)
is [`isTruthy()`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/req.html).
The package introduced the concept of truthy/falsy that “generally indicates
whether a value, when coerced to a `base::logical()`, is `TRUE` or `FALSE`”
(see the [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/req.html#details)).

```r
require(shiny, quietly = TRUE)

a <- "a"
b <- "b"
isTruthy(a == b) # FALSE >> works
#> [1] FALSE

a <- character(0)
isTruthy(a == b) # FALSE >> works
#> [1] FALSE

a <- NA
isTruthy(a == b) # FALSE >> works
#> [1] FALSE

a <- NULL
isTruthy(a == b) # FALSE >> works
#> [1] FALSE

a <- b
isTruthy(a == b) # TRUE >> works
#> [1] TRUE
```

One of the advantages is that you can use other operators like `%in%`
or `match()`, too.

The situation in R is that you never know what a function will return when it fails.
Some functions return `NA`, others `NULL`, and yet others vectors with length == 0.
`isTruthy()` makes it easier to handle the diversity.

Unfortunately, when one does not write a shiny app it hardly makes sense to load the package because - aside from `isTruthy` - shiny only adds a large bunch of unneeded Web App features.

<sup>Created on 2021-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>