# all() function gives TRUE but any() gives FALSE for same comparison

Tags: r, logic, comparison

The `any()` function is descripted with "[Given a set of logical vectors, is at least one of the values true?](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/any)" while the `all()` function says "[Given a set of logical vectors, are all of the values true](https://www.rdocumentation.org/search?q=all)?" This means that everything that returns `TRUE` in `all()` should return `TRUE` in `any()`, too. But see here:

```
all(NULL == "Yes")
[1] TRUE
any(NULL == "Yes")
[1] FALSE
```

I know that there is the `is.null()` function which gives same result for `all(is.null(NULL))` and `any(is.null(NULL))`. But `is.null()` is not what I need to use in my case. I am working on a function which contains user choices. Those choices can be a predefined word or NULL (if no choice is made). Of course I can revalue `NULL` internally to a word (i.e. "no_choice") but still, why is this happening that `any()` returns `FALSE`? Besides, the question is not that much about `is.null()` since `NULL == 1` gives `logical(0)` same paradox situation is true for:

```
all(logical(0))
[1] TRUE
any(logical(0))
[1] FALSE
```

**THIS IS A DUPLICATE**

Found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65637182/how-can-all-all-be-true-while-none-any-are-true-at-the-same-time) asking same paradox. I can not mark as duplicate (or do not know how).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs, `any` ignores zero-length objects:

> ...
> zero or more logical vectors. Other objects of zero length are ignored, and the rest are coerced to logical ignoring any class.

How is this related to `NULL == 1`?

If we break this down, we see that `NULL == 1` returns a `logical(0)` which is of length 0.

```
length(logical(0))
[1] 0
```

This is similar to:

```
any()
[1] FALSE
```

Now, why does `all` work?

> The value returned is TRUE if all of the values in x are TRUE (including if there are no values), and FALSE if at least one of the values in x is FALSE. Otherwise the value is NA (which can only occur if na.rm = FALSE and ... contains no FALSE values and at least one NA value).

Note the **including if there are no values** part.

Compare this to the part in `any`'s doc entry:

> The value returned is TRUE if at least one of the values in x is TRUE, and FALSE if all of the values in x are FALSE (including if there are no values)

I think the main point is that since one is comparing `NULL` with something else, the returned logical vector is empty (i.e. length zero) which affects how the result is dealt with by `any`/`all`.